# PyMC: summary statistics for a subset of variables

Tags: pymc

I'm using PyMC 2.3.4 and am trying to get summary statistics for a subset of my model variables, but can't seem to do so using the method in the docs.

Model-building code:

```
import pymc

a = pymc.Normal('a',0,1)
b = pymc.Normal('b',0,1)
myModel = pymc.Model((a,b))
M = pymc.MCMC(myModel)
M.sample(1000)
```

Per the documentation at https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/database.html, I should be able to run

```
M.a.summary() -> summary statistics for a
```

but instead, I get

```
AttributeError: 'MCMC' object has no attribute 'a'
```

However, `M.summary()` gives summary statistics for all variables.

Comment: I think I know what your question is, but please edit if my answer doesn't matching what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are perhaps too many ways to create a model in PyMC2.  The one you used, passing an iterable of `pymc.Node` instances, does not record the names, so the model doesn't have an `M.a`, even though `M.nodes` contains a stochastic named 'a'.

If you prefer to create your model this way, you can get a summary from `a` directly, with

```
a.summary()
```

For me, this prints

```
a:

    Mean             SD               MC Error        95% HPD interval
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    [[-0.016]]       [[ 0.992]]       [[ 0.031]]       [-1.986  1.939]


    Posterior quantiles:

    2.5             25              50              75             97.5
     |---------------|===============|===============|---------------|
    [[-2.047]]       [[-0.665]]      [[-0.058]]     [[ 0.672]]    [[ 1.937]]
```

I find it convenient to have the attribute `M.a` available sometimes, and you can get it by using a dictionary instead of a list when constructing the model:

```
M2 = pymc.MCMC({'a':a, 'b':b})
M2.sample(1000)
M2.a.summary()
```